# CRON vs Bash Script

Tags: bash, libreoffice, cron, 19.10

I have a bash script that works fine.  In the terminal, I can execute the script...  `./foo.bar`

1. The script closes soffice.bin,
2. Executes a python script that replaces the contents of the previously closed libreoffice file
3. Opens libreoffice with the file in question and displays it on my 2nd monitor.

This works like a charm when I personally execute this in my terminal window -UBUNTU 19.10.

I tried using CRON to automate the process.  But when CRON does the job ---

1. The script closes soffice.bin (libreoffice).
2. Executes a python script that replaces the contents of the previously closed file
3. Opens libreoffice with the file in question but does not open the window for "viewing".

I use this system to run a database server, but I have a monitor attached to display the daily information.  I guess I am trying to figure out why cron does the same thing except re-open libreoffice completely.  It hangs like it's trying to do a restore.  But my options in my BASH script on libreoffice are `--norestore`.